# Algorithm to generate every powerset of different lengths of a list?

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Given a list `{x1, x2, x3, x4, ..., xn}`, is there an algorithm that can generate every subset of this list? A subset in this case has to have a length `i` where `1 <= i <= n`. Also the ordering does not matter, for example this is a duplicate: `{x3, x4, x9}` is the same as `{x9, x3, x4}`, i.e don't put the duplicates in the output. Also the running time of the algorithm has to be `O(n^k)` for some constant integer `k>=0`.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: "Also the running time of the algorithm has to be O(n^k) for some constant integer k>=0." The number of subsets that you need to generate is `2^n`. No polynomial-time algorithm exists that could generate `O(2^n)` items.

Comment: That's not permutations. For permutations, ordering matters. I think what you mean is a powerset, which is the set of all subsets.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: Actually the number of subsets that OP needs to generate is n choose i, which in big-O notation, it's `O(2^i)` **Oops**: I thought OP only needs to generate the subsets for *a specific* `i`, apparently it's *for all* `i`. So yes, it's `O(2^n)`

Answer (score 1):

Every element of the original set may be present or absent in any given subset.  For an n-element list, run through the n-bit binary numbers in order, selecting the elements corresponding to a 1.  0b000...000 is the empty subset.  0b111...111 is the original set.  Every number in between is a possible subset.  All possible subsets will be included once and only once in the list.

For example, if the original set is {A, B, C}:

```
0 -> 000 -> {}
1 -> 001 -> {C}
2 -> 010 -> {B}
3 -> 011 -> {B, C}
4 -> 100 -> {A}
5 -> 101 -> {A, C}
6 -> 110 -> {A, B}
7 -> 111 -> {A, B, C}
```

If you require only subsets of a particular length, then use one of the binary 1-counting algorithms to eliminate those numbers/subsets that do not match.  Generating the numbers 0 to n is obviously O(n).  That brings it down to the binary 1-counting algorithm you use.  There is no need to eliminate duplicates since none are produced.

Answer (score 0):

Do some google search on backtracking.Its a standard problem you asked.